# Многопоточность на Python

Tags: python, многопоточность

Помогите разобраться с тем, как сделать многопоточность в Python.

Мне нужно одновременно запустить запись видео и запись звука, и то и другое по отдельности есть и работает, но как запустить их одновременно, непонятно.

Есть код:

```
import threading
def proc(n):
    print "Процесс", n
    p1 = threading.Thread(target=proc, name="t1", args=["1"])
    p2 = threading.Thread(target=proc, name="t2", args=["2"])
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

Пытаюсь разобраться, но никак не выходит. Что куда вставлять объясните, пожалуйста, на пальцах.

Comment: *"никак не выходит."* -- что *конкретно* вы пробовали, что ожидали получить и что вместо этого происходит? Опишите шаг за шагом, добавьте полное сообщение об ошибке и приведите минимальный самодостаточный пример кода, который показывает вашу проблему. Код в вопросе похож на fork bomb -- не запускайте его -- не понятно, какое отношение он к записи видео/аудио имеет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В частности этот код будет "плодить" бесконечное количество потоков с именами "t1" и "t2". А вообще тема многопоточности в питоне раскрыта в сети и в литературе весьма широко. Вот на мой взгляд отличная статья, как раз для начинающих http://habrahabr.ru/post/149420/ сходите, почитайте - если вопросы будут задавайте!

P. S. Если у вас есть и то и другое (не сразу увидел), то можно сделать так:

```
import threading

def proc_video():
    # код реализующий процесс записи видео
    pass

def proc_audio():
    # код реализующий процесс записи аудио
    pass

thread_video = threading.Thread(target=proc_video, name="proc_video")
thread_audio = threading.Thread(target=proc_audio, name="proc_audio")

thread_video.start()
thread_audio.start()

thread_video.join()
thread_audio.join()
```

Однако нужно помнить про GIL http://habrahabr.ru/post/167733/, и если такой подход не подойдет можно воспользоваться модулем multiprocessing, а не threading, там параллельность достигается за счет процессов, и нет ни какого GIL и интерфейс у него такой же как и у threading (то есть можно просто импортировать multiprocessing, а не threading и работать с ним также).

Comment: Огромное спасибо ! все работает но только если добавить -thread_video.start()
thread_audio.start()   

но появилась такая проблема - запускаю код все работает (записывает) , я довольный закрываю Python а запись видео и аудио продолжается ... и остановить ее можно только через диспетчер задач ,найдя там процесс pythonw. Как решить данную проблему подскажите пожалуйста !

Comment: jfs, да верное замечание - поправил!

Comment: @Игорь, для остановки потока можно вызвать функцию exit(int code) из модуля sys, чтобы точнее ответить, нужно больше вашего кода.

Comment: вот код - 
`import threading
import os
import time
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab

def proc_video():
    # код реализующий процесс записи видео
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start < 3600:
          img = ImageGrab.grab()
          saveas = os.path.join("D:/Games/" + time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S") + ".png")
          img.save(saveas)
          time.sleep(2)
    pass
def proc_audio():
    # код реализующий процесс записи аудио
    print "какое-нибудь слово..."
    pass`  продолжение - в след. комментарии ----

Comment: `thread_video = threading.Thread(target=proc_video, name="proc_video")
thread_audio = threading.Thread(target=proc_audio, name="proc_audio")


thread_video.start()
thread_audio.start()`

Comment: Pythonа закрываешь а скриншоты продолжают делаться.  заходишь в диспетчер задач находишь процесс python , его закрываешь и тогда скриншоты перестают делаться.
если использовать как вы советуете ---exit(int code) из модуля sys--- то это ничего не даст в данном положении, так как закрытие программы произойдет когда до нее дойдет очередь по коду. или же я где- то туплю???

Comment: Я бы завел  переменную-флаг (stop) в основном потоке, которую проверял бы в потоках proc_video, proc_audio, и в случае если она True - вызывал бы sys.exit(code), а значение переменной stop менял бы в основном потоке.ну например можно реализовать интерактивное управление через пользовательский ввод в терминальное окно и т. д.

Comment: @Игорь: вы можете [отредактировать ваш вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/471446/edit), вместо того чтобы код в комментарии пытаться засунуть (любая информация необходимая для ответа на вопрос, должна быть в самом вопросе)

Comment: @triplustri, ага понял, буду пробовать, спасибо большое за помощь !

Comment: @jfs, это я понимаю но на основной та вопрос я ответ получил а, необходимость засунуть код в комментарий возникла уже попутно из-за другой проблемы ...

Answer (score 1):

Имхо, но лично мне для моих целей всегда удобно создавать отдельных класс, наследуемый от класса Thread и переопределять в нем метод run(). Примерно так:

```
class MyThread(Thread):
    
    def run(self):
        # твой код, который должен быть выполнен в потоке
```

Также преимуществом этого способа является хороший контроль потока, можно добавить/изменить конструктор потока, передавать переменные в конструктор и бла-бла-бла.